# OCaml precedence

Tags: ocaml, operator-keyword, operator-precedence

I'm not familiar with OCaml, but have been involved in analysing some OCaml code.
This piece of code puzzles me. What is the correct grouping, based on operator precedence?

```
let new_fmt () =
  let b = new_buf () in
  let fmt = Format.formatter_of_buffer b in
  (fmt,
   fun () ->
    Format.pp_print_flush fmt ();
    let s = Buffer.contents b in
    Buffer.reset b;
    s
  )
```

There are three operators here: ";", "," and "fun". Based on the reference manual the precedence
order is comma > semicolon > fun, which I believe leads to the following groupings below.
Which one is picked by the OCaml compiler? Or is there another grouping that is the correct one?

grouping 1:

```
  let new_fmt () =
  let b = new_buf () in
  let fmt = Format.formatter_of_buffer b in
  ((fmt,
   fun () ->
    Format.pp_print_flush fmt ());
    (let s = Buffer.contents b in
    Buffer.reset b;
    s)
  )
```

grouping 2:

```
let new_fmt () =
  let b = new_buf () in
  let fmt = Format.formatter_of_buffer b in
  (fmt,
   (fun () ->
    Format.pp_print_flush fmt ();
    let s = Buffer.contents b in
    (Buffer.reset b;
     s))
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

grouping 2 is the correct one.

If you are unsure about how things are parsed, editor helpers may help you (sometimes): ocaml-mode or tuareg-mode (and probably other editor helpers) should give you auto-indentations corresponding with how the code is parsed:

```
let new_fmt () =
    let b = new_buf () in
    let fmt = Format.formatter_of_buffer b in
    ( fmt,
      fun () ->
         Format.pp_print_flush fmt ();
         let s = Buffer.contents b in
         Buffer.reset b;
         s
    )
```

The identation of `let s = ...` is below `fun () ->` which means that that part is within `fun () -> ...`. If it *were* outside of `fun () ->` it should be indented differently, in the same level of `fun () ->`.

Another, very precise but probably over complex way is to examine how the code is parsed directly by `ocamlc -dparsetree source.ml`.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, there is another operator used in the code. It's represented by no symbols: the operation of applying a function to a value in OCaml is represented by juxtaposition. This operator has higher precedence than the others.

This code

```
fun () -> a ; b
```

parses as

```
fun () -> (a; b)
```

not as

```
(fun () -> a) ; b
```

It follows because as you say `;` has higher precedence than `fun` (though this terminology is a little suspect).

Similarly

```
let c = d in e; f
```

parses as

```
let c = d in (e; f)
```

not as

```
(let c = d in e); f
```

So, the final expression parses like this:

```
(fmt,
 fun () -> (Format.pp_print_flush fmt ();
            let s = Buffer.contents b in
            (Buffer.reset b; s))
)
```